# Need to design a complex HTML table

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I need to design a HTML table as the attachment below but I seem to be struggling due to my lack of understanding in HTML table.

This is what I've come up with so far but as you can see, it's not even close to the end result. I hope that someone can point me in the right direction.

```
<section class="mb-5">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <!-- Heading -->
        <h2 class="mb-3">
          Task activities reports
        </h2>

        <div class="table-responsive border">
          <table class="table mb-0">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Service</th>
                <th scope="col">Category</th>
                <th scope="col">
                  <table>
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th colspan="10">Percent completed</th>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>10%</th>
                        <th>20%</th>
                        <th>30%</th>
                        <th>40%</th>
                        <th>50%</th>
                        <th>60%</th>
                        <th>70%</th>
                        <th>80%</th>
                        <th>90%</th>
                        <th>100%</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                  </table>
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Clipping path</td>
                <td>Category 1</td>
                <td>
                  <table>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>0</td>
                      <td>0</td>
                      <td>0</td>
                      <td>0</td>
                      <td>2</td>
                      <td>3</td>
                      <td>0</td>
                      <td>0</td>
                      <td>0</td>
                      <td>1</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[image]

Comment: so what is your question ?

Comment: The attributes `colspan` and `rowspan` are what you need for the header. Not nested tables.

Comment: colspan and rowspan are your friends

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `colspan` and `rowspan` attributes, not nested tables. `colspan` tells a cell to span the width of two columns, and `rowspan` tells it to span the height of two rows.

I've rendered your header rows and the first three rows of content based on what I said here. The rest of the table content follows the same principles.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">Service</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Category</th>
      <th colspan="11">Percent completed</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>10%</th>
      <th>20%</th>
      <th>30%</th>
      <th>40%</th>
      <th>50%</th>
      <th>60%</th>
      <th>70%</th>
      <th>80%</th>
      <th>90%</th>
      <th>100%</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="6">Clipping Path</td>
      <td>Category 1</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>1000</td>
      <td>1005</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Category 2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>1100</td>
      <td>1105</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Category 3</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>1200</td>
      <td>1209</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I've added CSS for borders so you can see the edges of the cells.

It's a little hard to get used to at first, because you have to ignore the presence of the cells in the rows where they "grow" to from where they were declared. Thus I've applied `rowspan="2"` to the Service heading, and that cell "grows" into the next row, along with Category. So that 10% heading shows up below Percent (since it only spans 1 row) because Service and Category are taking up space in the row though never declared in the `<tr>`.

Comment: The idea of colspan and rowspan was extremely useful and I was able to design the exact same table as previously shown.